# Want to learn Linux porting on an ARM platform

Tags: linux, embedded

I am looking to learn porting various flavors of Linux on ARM boards. I was about to buy TI's Panda board or Beagle board. I want to learn customizing Linux source code, compile it and port on one of these boards.

I was just curious if there are any other boards with a good community support than the TI ones that will be good for beginners.

Some of the other options I could find in the Internet are:

- Snapdragon 8x60 mobile platform with Android
- i.MX31 product development kit (very expensive)
- Tegra 250 development board

Comment: I don't understand what porting you will do; Linux already runs fine on these.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I want to learn how to compile the source code of linux and boot one of these boards with the compiled version of linux on it. I want to learn how the boot up process of OS happens and probably run some small application. I am not trying to do something new, just wanted to learn the existing process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, building a kernel by yourself is really hard work, and build an embedded kernel is much much difficult. Maybe you can try to play with some prebuild kernel images, and then try to configure it by your own.

I have a [BeagleBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard) and at first I used these Ubuntu ARM ports, the link number 3 have the kernel image (you can install USB and Wi-Fi support really easy):

- [Install Ubuntu-ARM on the BeagleBoard](http://automatica.com.au/2009/10/howto-ubuntu-on-the-beagleboard/)
- [Ubuntu ARM ports](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/)
- [Ubuntu ARM kernel images](http://rcn-ee.net/deb/)

Or maybe, if you like [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian), here is some information about the ARM port installation:

- [Install embedded Debian on the BeagleBoard](http://www.lirtex.com/embedded/installing-embedded-debian-on-the-beagleboard/)
- [ELinux BeagleBoard, embedded Debian information](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardDebian)

Or if you know how to configure and build a kernel, or maybe if you have a little of [Gentoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux) experience, you can test this:

- [Gentoo manual and kernel image on the BeagleBoard](https://www.slashorg.net/index.php?id=48)
- [Gentoo cross-development page information](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/embedded/cross-development.xml)
- [Gentoo ARM handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-arm.xml)
- [Gentoo ARM port overlay (Git)](http://gitorious.org/gentoo-arm-overlay)

And if you have a [PandaBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PandaBoard), this guy have a lot of documentation on it:

- [Gentoo PandaBoard install howto](http://dev.gentoo.org/~armin76/arm/pandaboard/install.xml)
- [Gentoo ARM files and information](http://dev.gentoo.org/~armin76/arm/)
- [Gentoo PandaBoard files and information](http://dev.gentoo.org/~armin76/arm/pandaboard/)

Check the BeagleBoard wiki page and eLinux page, they have a lot of documentation about the board, NAND configuration, Linux distributions, devices, etc.

- [BeagleBoard page](http://beagleboard.org/)
- [eLinux BeagleBoard information](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoard)

Or you can play with [QEMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QEMU) and configure an ARM virtual machine.